# Save a screen capture to a gif using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif, recording

I'm trying to record a JS animation from my browser and turn it into a high-quality gif.

Is there anything wrong with the following code?

Or a much better way to do this that I'm missing?

```
    webbrowser.open_new('test.html')

    start_time = time.time()

    with mss() as sct:
        # Part of the screen to capture
        monitor = {"top": 350, "left": 50, "width": 500, "height": 400}

        gif = []
        images = []
        frames = 1000

        while "Screen capturing":
            last_time = time.time()
            # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
            img = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))

            images.append(img)

            print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))
            frames -= 1

            if frames == 0:
                break

for img in images:
    im = Image.fromarray(img)
    gif.append(im)
    print(len(gif))

gif[0].save('test' + '.gif', save_all=True,optimize=False, append_images=gif[1:], duration=10, loop=0)
```

Comment: Well, one thing that's wrong with it is that it's not indented properly. Also `mss()` is undefined. Since you're using PIL, things might be easier if you used its [`ImageGrab`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageGrab.html) module.

Comment: Your right, the first part is inside a for loop and I didn't include

Will try the ImageGrab! thanks